# How to enable "Don't summarize" check box in chart expert data tab

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I want to use the default value from 'value' field and do not want to summarize it. But the "Don't Summarize" option is disabled in Chart Expert.

How can I enable this option and get the default value for my field?

Answer (score 0):

Don't summarize option is available only for formula fields only then it will work.